# Insert Building Blocks using Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to insert a formatted table that I have saved in word named "DV Table" as part of the building blocks using VBA. I need this table to be inserted at the 13th paragraph of the word document.
Here's my code below. The first 3 lines just sets the selection to be at the 12th paragraph and create a new paragraph (13) after that. The last line of code is to insert the table. But when I run this, it gives the error.

> Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined

I guess that this is not the proper way of defining the location. Would like some help on this. Thanks.

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(12).Range.Select
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.Paragraphs.Add

 ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("DV Table" _
      ).Insert Where:=Paragraphs(13).Range.Select, RichText:=True
```

Comment: I'd suggest you learn how to use F1. Place the cursor in a keyword and press F1. This will bring up the MS help page for that keyword. Then read the help paying particular attention to the return type, if any.

Comment: can you help example on [support microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/922846/error-message-when-you-run-a-recorded-macro-to-insert-a-cover-page-in)

Comment: Are you still struggling with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Where` parameter requires a `Range` object. There are two problems with `Paragraphs(13).Range.Select`

- it's a method - it's an action, *selecting* something, not returning an object
- `Paragraphs(13)` isn't "fully qualified" - VBA doesn't know what it is/what is meant.

One possibility would be

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(13).Range
```

Notice `ActiveDocument.` preceding `Paragraphs`: this "fully qualifies" `Paragraphs(13)` - it tells VBA to what that belongs. And, since `Where` requires a `Range` object, `Paragraphs(13).Range` should be a correct "target" (I have not tested your code).

Generally, it's preferable *not* to work with `Selection`, just with `Range` objects. There's usually no need to actually *select* something using VBA. An alternative to the code snippet in the question could be

```
Dim rng As Word.Range

Set rng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(13).Range
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd    'like pressing right-arrow for a selection
rng.InsertParagraphAfter
rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart  ' like pressing left-arrow for a selection
'rng.Select                   ' for testing / demo purposes
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("DV Table" _
               ).Insert Where:=rng, RichText:=True
```

In this case, the selection in the document does not change. There's no screen flicker; and code executes more quickly. This way of working takes getting used to, but once one is familiar with it, it's much easier to recognize what the code should be doing... `Selection` is rather vague as to what is being manipulated, especially if there's a lot of code using it.